# how to dynamically purge the tables in AQADMIN

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I was trying to purge the QUEUE tables dynamically, I'm getting an error.Below is the code

```
 set serveroutput on;
declare
l_stmt varchar2(2000):='';
po_t dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;
BEGIN
for i in (select NAME,queue_table from all_Queues where owner='AQADMIN') loop
--dbms_output.put_line(i.queue_table);
l_stmt:='DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE ('''||i.queue_table||''',''trunc(enq_time)<sysdate-90'',block => po_t)';
execute immediate l_stmt;
--dbms_output.put_line(l_stmt);
commit;
end loop;
END;
/
```

Error message:

```
Error report -
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 8
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

To know if my query is framing correctly, I commented out the execute immediate part and uncommented the DBMS_OUTPUT command, and the result was posted in sql developer and it executed perfectly, (below is the code output) .so the query is correct, not sure what was wrong with my code,

Output:

```
anonymous block completed

    DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE ('HEARTBEAT_MSG_QT','trunc(enq_time)<sysdate-90',block => po_t)
```

then I executed the above output in separate SQL block and it ran fine.Below

```
declare
po_t dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;
begin
DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE ('HEARTBEAT_MSG_QT','trunc(enq_time)<sysdate-90',po_t);
end;
/
```

anonymous block completed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `execute immediate` it is [expecting dynamic *SQL*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8), not PL/SQL. To run a PL/SQL command you need to wrap it in an anonymous block, just as you did when you ran it manually:

```
l_stmt:='DECLARE po_t dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t; BEGIN DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE ('''||i.queue_table||''',''trunc(enq_time)<sysdate-90'',block => po_t); END;';
```

or split onto multiple line to make it slightly easier to read:

```
l_stmt:='DECLARE po_t dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;'
  || 'BEGIN '
  || 'DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE ('''||i.queue_table||''','
  || '''trunc(enq_time)<sysdate-90'',block => po_t);'
  || 'END;';
```

Notice that you have to re-declare `po_t` inside that block as that the original declaration is out of scope for the dynamic SQL call (actually, the original one is now redundant...).

You don't need to use dynamic SQL though, you can pass the cursor value straight to the procedure:

```
DECLARE
  l_po dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;
BEGIN
  for i in (select NAME,queue_table from all_Queues where owner='AQADMIN') 
  loop
    DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE (queue_table => i.queue_table,
      purge_condition => 'trunc(enq_time)<sysdate-90'
      purge_options=> l_po);
  end loop;
END;
/
```

I've also removed the `commit` as it's redundant; [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_AQADM.html#GUID-339C9A49-E4CE-4D64-BB71-82E2DEBC837F):

> This procedure commits batches of messages in autonomous transactions.

Comment: Thanks a ton.It worked  .....declare 
po_t dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;
BEGIN
  for i in (select NAME,queue_table from all_Queues where owner='AQADMIN') 
  loop
    DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE (i.queue_table, 'trunc(enq_time)<sysdate-90',po_t);
  end loop;
END;
/

Comment: @AnishGopinath - sorry, yes, i was treating that as a constant not a type; so you do need to be declare and pass the variable.